# Nginx server redirect being ignored

Tags: nginx, redirect, https, 301-redirect

I'm must be stuffing this up somewhere but can't see where.  Nginx appears to be ignoring the following redirect.

This currently resides in its own conf file, but I have placed it in the other files.

```
server {
    server_name      domain.com;
    listen 80;
    rewrite         https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This is the ssl config, which works:

```
#HTTPS
server {
    listen      10.10.15.30:443 ssl;
    ssl         on;
    server_name domain.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/ssl-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/ssl-error.log;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.key;
    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # So the original HTTP Host header is preserved
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    # The IP address of the client (which might be a proxy itself)
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    add_header       Front-End-Https    on;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

}

Heres config for the backend servers, which works:

```
upstream backend {
  server 10.10.15.21 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
  server 10.10.15.22 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
}

#HTTP
server {
  listen 10.10.15.30:80 default_server;
  #listen 80;
  server_name _;
  location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      # So the original HTTP Host header is preserved
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      # The IP address of the client (which might be a proxy itself)
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}


server {
    listen 10.10.3.10:61709;
    location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    }
}
```

The backend servers handle multiple sites.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: So the redirect at the very top is being ignored.  When I go to domain.com there is no redirection to https

Comment: Did you restart nginx?

Comment: yeah restarted the server.  I'm on the brink of rebooting.

Comment: And you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Thanks I got it working.  So it something to do with the precedence when Nginx loads the config.  Should I add the new config to the original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this what I changed to get it working:

mv /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.com.ssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.com.sslconf

Then I edited /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.com.sslconf and added the following to the top:

```
server {
  listen      10.10.15.30:80;
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Then I edited /etc/nginx/conf.d/backends.conf and added the following below the main server:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.sslconf;
```

Its something to do with the precedence/order loading of configuration.

If this isn't clear I can post full config up and highlight changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `^` in rewrite.

```
server {
    server_name      domain.com;
    listen 80;
    rewrite          ^    https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't this.  I'll add the changed config.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of loop?  Does it work if you put 'break' in there?

The way I read it, you can only have one flag on a rewrite rule, so try this first for testing:

```
server {
  server_name      domain.com;
  listen 80;
  rewrite          ^    https://$server_name$request_uri? break;
}
```

Since your rewrite should always match, you should be able to get the permanent redirect status in like so:

```
server {
  server_name      domain.com;
  listen 80;
  rewrite          ^    https://$server_name$request_uri? break;
  return   301;
}
```

Alternatively, try the 'break' directive.